# WooCommerce separate variation relationship

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, by default, when we have, say, 2 attributes, and then we create a number of variations, they will be the result of every term multiplied by each other, meaning if we have 10 term of attribute A and 7 term of attribute B, it will create 70 variations maximum.

I want to make them separate in controlling the option, and it may have the same meaning as "making the attribute A and attribute B not connected", or "dynamic variation relationship".

For example: I have attribute: **Color** and **Size**. Color has 5 terms: White, Black, Red, Blue, Green. Size has 3 terms: Small, Medium, Large.

For every color, there will be an individual image represents every product regardless of what size is selected. And so does with the sizes. For every size, there will be a different price but each will have the same price for every color.

Also, when I select on a size variation, I need the image slideshow not to be updated (which it does by default, see this GIF below). I just need to update the price.

[image: Selecting a size variation updates the image slideshow.]

What should I change in the WooCommerce code, database, and what do you suggest for the backend and frontend?

I hope you understand my explanation and am looking forward for your help. If you need some clarification or more explanation, I will edit this question.